# Qual è il significato di "dare il passaggio" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Ma il mio amore è Paco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Il locale era zeppo, di gente che non **dava il passaggio** nemmeno a sfondarle la schiena.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "dare il passaggio" in questa frase? Significa lasciare passare? Alla voce "passaggio" di parecchi dizionari ho trovato che "dare un passaggio" vuol dire offrire gratuitamente un breve viaggio nella propria auto, ma non mi sembra che questo abbia molto senso nel brano sopra citato.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credo che il significato di ***dare il passaggio*** nel contesto da te citato sia cedere il passo, cioè lasciare passare, come da te ipotizzato.

Da Treccani per [cedere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cedere/):

> 2a. *c. il passo*, tirarsi in disparte per lasciar passare qualcuno;

Il locale era pieno di gente che non si spostava per lasciarlo passare neanche con la forza.